# Accessibility : Broken Skip Link Error on "Skeleton" Theme

Tags: theming, navigation

I installed the "Skeleton" theme and found it has a "Broken Skip Link" by using "wave.webaim.org". How can I find and fix where is this "Broken Skip Link"?

You can find this Skeleton demo at "http://demo.drupalizing.com/skeleton"

and the "Broken Skip Link" error at "http://wave.webaim.org/report#/http://demo.drupalizing.com/skeleton/"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Skeleton theme. it has:

```
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
```

But it has no anchor tag for `main-content`. You should file an issue for the Project on Drupal.org.

You can fix this by supplying a patch to the theme project that alters `html.tpl.php` or `page.tpl.php` to include an `<a name="main-content"></a>` at the top of the content area. You may do this in your own subtheme as well of course simply by modifying the necessary TPL file.

**EDIT**:
Issue created at Drupal.org https://drupal.org/node/2211661

Comment: Ty @tenken ! Adding "<a name="main-content"></a>" does resolve the error message, however I still dont know where can modify the code you mentioned. which is <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://drupal.org/comment/8551121#comment-8551121 for an explanation and a patch file.